# paste data into active cells

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I write a very simple code

```
Sub copy_unibeton_muss()
Worksheets("source").Range("a8:c8").Copy
End Sub
```

The code will copy the range `A8:C8`. I added another portion to paste active cells in the active selected range.

```
Destination:=ActiveCell
```

But unfortunately the code paste only the data in the first row onlly. I need to paste data in all selected range may be **5x3** or **6x3** whatever I needed.

Comment: You need to match the destination range area with the source area.

Comment: You don't need to match the areas when using Selection/ActiveCell for the destination - the copied range will be copied in full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Worksheets("source").Range("a8:c8").CopY Destination:= Selection
```

This will work as expected provided Selection has same number of columns of copied range